# Need to retrieve title, description and uploaded image in a row and display them using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a file named contact-form-submission.php in which I insert the form data into Database. In contact-form-submission.php I insert the Name, Message and upload the logo into uploads folder.

Here is the code of contact-form-submission.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("posts", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_message = $_POST['contact_message'];
if($contact_name !='' && $contact_message !='' && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (name, message) VALUES ('$contact_name', '$contact_message')");
    echo "<br/><h2>Data Inserted successfully...!! Redirecting to Offer Add page in 5 seconds</h2>";
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}
else{
    echo "<h2>Insertion Failed <br/> Offer Add Fields are Blank....!! Redirecting to Offer Add page in 5 seconds</h2>";
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}

//$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the form page coding - index.php

```
<div class="col-sm-12">

                <?php
                // check for a successful form post  
                if (isset($_GET['s']))
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">" . $_GET['s'] . "</div>";

                // check for a form error  
                elseif (isset($_GET['e']))
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">" . $_GET['e'] . "</div>";
                ?>
                <form role="form" method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="input1">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <label for="input4">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="6" id="input4"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label for="input1">Logo</label>
                            <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Upload" id="fileToUpload">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

When the form in Index.php is submitted it will call the contact-form-submission.php and it will insert title and message and also upload the image to 'uploads' folder.

In Lists.php I display the title, message and the uploaded image separately. But the issue is I need to display, title, message and image in a single row.

Here is the code of Lists.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "posts";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, message, logo FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "- Message " . $row["message"]. "<br>";
      echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "- Message " . $row["message"]. "Logo: ". "<img src='uploads". $row["logo"] ." />". "<br>";

}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}        
        //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
       $folder = "uploads";
       $results = scandir('uploads');
       foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
            echo '
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                        <p><a href="remove.php?name='.$result.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Remove</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
       }

$conn->close();
?>
```

In Lists.php I need to show the contact_name, contact_message and uploaded logo in a single row. But now the contact_name and contact_message is displayed separately and the logos are shown separately.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your issue seems like the html/css issue and not the php. Can you past view-source of html page of lists.php so we can take that debug as it looks like your img tag have some kind of float or css style which might be dragging the image to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table to display in the rows:
below code will help you
Replace it with your while loop.

```
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<tr><td>id:</td><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td> <td> Name: </td><td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td> Message </td><td>" . $row["message"]. "</td><td>Logo:</td><td>". "<img src='uploads". $row["logo"] ." />". "</td></tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
```

query should be like this

```
INSERT INTO posts (name, message,logo) VALUES ('$contact_name', '$contact_message','$target_file')
```

Comment: I replaced my while loop with your code, but I'm unable to view the uploaded images. I tried by adding a new entry, but uploaded image is not showing up.

Comment: change src uploads to uploads/ in img tag

Comment: Changed to uploads/, but still not able to view. Should I change the method of uploading the file to uploads folder? Because in my database in 'logo' column I don't insert anything. You can check in 'contact-form-submission.php'

Comment: okay, inserted $target_file, now in 'logo' column I have '[BLOB - 17 B]' but still not able to view the image.

Comment: okay, inserted $target_file, now in 'logo' column I have '[BLOB - 17 B]' but still not able to view the image.

Comment: check image src that it is correct or wrong by inspect element

Comment: this is the source in Inspect element <img src="uploadsuploads/5index.jpg /></td></tr><tr><td>id:</td><td>27</td> <td> Name: </td><td>dasfds</td><td> Message </td><td>asdfasdf</td><td>Logo:</td><td><img src=" uploadsuploads="" 5index.jpg="">

Comment: I think the source is wrong. Please see above comment

Comment: remove "'uploads" from  **<img src='uploads". $row["logo"] ." />** . It should look like this    **<img src='". $row["logo"] ."' />**